# Global context in Flutter while using MaterialApp.router()

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigation

I want to know if there is a way to use a **Global Context** in a Flutter App while using auto route as ***MaterialApp.router() don't have a navigatorKey***.

Answer (score 2):

Specify scaffoldMessengerKey to MaterialApp:

```
final snackbarKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

...

MaterialApp(
  scaffoldMessengerKey: snackbarKey,
```

You can get the context from GlobalKey:

```
snackbarKey.currentState?.context
```

If you need a context for navigation, you must use the navigator context. Create a global key and pass it to [RootRouter](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/blob/723a2fdfdc1c1364bbe7e19a1781ddc74f39ebe0/auto_route/example/lib/mobile/router/router.gr.dart):

```
late final RootRouter appRouter;
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

...

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  appRouter = RootRouter(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  );
}
```

Now you can get the context and use it to navigate:

```
navigatorKey.currentState?.context
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just tried it it return an error: "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.". This will normally work if not using the router but in my case it do not.

Comment: If you need context for navigation use navigatorKey. It can be passed to the RootRouter https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/blob/723a2fdfdc1c1364bbe7e19a1781ddc74f39ebe0/auto_route/example/lib/mobile/router/router.gr.dart

Comment: @Vitali thanks, you should provide your comment as an actual answer (edit your current answer)